# Why does typing 'q' exit vim? (.man file)

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, macro

When I type the character `q` on my keyboard in vim, it exits vim. Why?

Today I tried it edit a file with the file extension `.man`. I wanted to edit the file with a macro, so I tried to type `qq` -- but when the first `q` was entered, `vim` closed!

```
vim test.man
```

This is on a fresh install on Debian 12. I do not have a `.vimrc` defined.

I renamed the same file with a `.man` extension to have a `.txt` extension, and this time I could create a macro as expected -- typing a `q` doesn't cause `vim` to exit.

```
mv test.man test.txt
vim test.txt
```

Why is vim exiting when typing a `q` when trying to edit a file with a `.man` file extension? And how do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Ugh.  This type of automagic for a fresh install is not to be encouraged.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Vim editor will load the `man` filetype plugin (`ft-man-plugin`) whenever it opens a file which has a `.man` filename suffix.

A more usable way of using this plugin is by loading it with

```
:runtime ftplugin/man.vim
```

... and then using the `:Man` command, e.g.,

```
:Man ls
```

**One of the things the `man` filetype plugin changes is that it maps `q` to `:quit`.** It does this because the `:Man` command usually runs within Vim, and quitting it brings you back to whatever other document you were writing at the time, and someone decided it would be handier to just have to type `q`, as you would usually do to exit out of the manual pager in the terminal.

For more information, see [`:help ft-man-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ft-man-plugin) in Vim.

**To avoid loading this plugin for `.man` files**, set the filetype of files with this filename suffix to something else, e.g., `text`, in your Vim startup file (`~/.vimrc` or wherever you configure Vim):

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.man set filetype=text
```

Or, remove the filetype detection completely for these files:

```
autocmd! filetypedetect BufRead,BufNewFile *.man
```